# What are my rights when I wasn't invited to a shareholder meeting?

Tags: shares, board-of-directors, rights-issue

I am a shareholder (roughly 20%) and do not have board representation.  The company had a shareholder meeting which I was not invited to or aware of.  I got a letter in the mail stating that the meeting was held and the board of directors were re elected.  Doesn't the company have a requirement to inform me of a shareholder meeting and don't I have a right to vote etc?

Comment: What does the shareholder agreement state on the issue? This will vary wildly by company and country.

Comment: Not sure- actually not even sure where it is.

Comment: You need to get a copy of the by-laws.  They *might* be filed with the relevant state's Secretary Of State.

Comment: It _may_ also depend on whether your shares hold any voting rights or not. If they _don't_, there _may_ be less requirement to inform those shareholders (depending on the jurisdiction, and whether this is a private or public-listed company).

Comment: What is your jurisdiction? Corporate law in your jurisdiction will provide guidance on shareholder rights, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> I am a shareholder (roughly 20%) and do not have board representation.

Why? Seriously, 20% makes you a major investor in pretty much any company.

> Doesn't the company have a requirement to inform me of a shareholder meeting and don't I 
>   have a right to vote etc?

You own 20%. Yes, they do have to invite you of a meeting of people ONWNING them.

That is, IF this is a standard setup and you have shares allowing a stanard vote, which gives you 20% of the votes.

Not if your shares do not have any rights. Which you should know - you got them, you should have read the shareholders agreement and relevant by-laws.